# Trying Curve on a Sphere. Can't seem to get the rise and fall of the curve right

Tags: processing

Was trying something like this:
[image]

But my curves were all wrong..And I ended up with something like this. 
[image]

The code is inserted below:

```
float angle;
float r = 200;

Table table;
PImage earth;
PShape globe;

int rowCount;

void setup() {
  background(51);
  size(600, 600, P3D);

  table = new Table("From_USA_Coordinates.tsv");
  rowCount = table.getRowCount();
  earth = loadImage("world.topo.bathy.200406.3x5400x2700.jpg");

  noStroke();
  globe = createShape(SPHERE, r);
  globe.setTexture(earth);
}

void draw() {
  background(51);
  text("From USA to other Parts of the World", width/2, 50);
  textAlign(CENTER);
  translate(width/2, height/2);
  //rotateY(angle);
  //angle += 0.005;

  //lights();
  noStroke();
  shape(globe);

  for(int row = 0; row < rowCount; row++){

    float USALatitude = table.getFloat(row, 3);
    float USALongitude = table.getFloat(row, 4);
    float tripCountryLatitude = table.getFloat(row, 5);
    float tripCountryLongitude = table.getFloat(row, 6);
    int tripCountryOccurance = table.getInt(row, 2);   

    float tripTheta = radians(tripCountryLatitude);
    float tripPhi = radians(tripCountryLongitude) + PI;
    float USATheta = radians(USALatitude);
    float USAPhi = radians(USALongitude);

    float x1 = r * cos(USATheta) * cos(USAPhi);
    float y1 = -r * sin(USATheta);
    float z1 = -r * cos(USATheta) * sin(USAPhi);

    float x2 = r * cos(tripTheta) * cos(tripPhi);
    float y2 = -r * sin(tripTheta);
    float z2 = -r * cos(tripTheta) * sin(tripPhi);    

    pushMatrix();
    noFill();
    stroke(255);
    bezier(x1, y1, z1, x1+150, y1+240, z1+150, x2-300, y2-150, z2-190, x2, y2, z2);
    popMatrix();   
  }  
  noLoop();  
}
```

Table Class:

```
class Table {
  int rowCount;
  String[][] data;


  Table(String filename) {
    String[] rows = loadStrings(filename);
    data = new String[rows.length][];

    for (int i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
      if (trim(rows[i]).length() == 0) {
        continue; // skip empty rows
      }
      if (rows[i].startsWith("#")) {
        continue;  // skip comment lines
      }

      // split the row on the tabs
      String[] pieces = split(rows[i], TAB);
      // copy to the table array
      data[rowCount] = pieces;
      rowCount++;

      // this could be done in one fell swoop via:
      //data[rowCount++] = split(rows[i], TAB);
    }
    // resize the 'data' array as necessary
    data = (String[][]) subset(data, 0, rowCount);
  }


  int getRowCount() {
    return rowCount;
  }


  // find a row by its name, returns -1 if no row found
  int getRowIndex(String name) {
    for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
      if (data[i][0].equals(name)) {
        return i;
      }
    }
    println("No row named '" + name + "' was found");
    return -1;
  }


  String getRowName(int row) {
    return getString(row, 0);
  }


  String getString(int rowIndex, int column) {
    return data[rowIndex][column];
  }


  String getString(String rowName, int column) {
    return getString(getRowIndex(rowName), column);
  }


  int getInt(String rowName, int column) {
    return parseInt(getString(rowName, column));
  }


  int getInt(int rowIndex, int column) {
    return parseInt(getString(rowIndex, column));
  }


  float getFloat(String rowName, int column) {
    return parseFloat(getString(rowName, column));
  }


  float getFloat(int rowIndex, int column) {
    return parseFloat(getString(rowIndex, column));
  }


  void setRowName(int row, String what) {
    data[row][0] = what;
  }


  void setString(int rowIndex, int column, String what) {
    data[rowIndex][column] = what;
  }


  void setString(String rowName, int column, String what) {
    int rowIndex = getRowIndex(rowName);
    data[rowIndex][column] = what;
  }


  void setInt(int rowIndex, int column, int what) {
    data[rowIndex][column] = str(what);
  }


  void setInt(String rowName, int column, int what) {
    int rowIndex = getRowIndex(rowName);
    data[rowIndex][column] = str(what);
  }


  void setFloat(int rowIndex, int column, float what) {
    data[rowIndex][column] = str(what);
  }


  void setFloat(String rowName, int column, float what) {
    int rowIndex = getRowIndex(rowName);
    data[rowIndex][column] = str(what);
  }  
}
```

Link to my data set:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1W169RaiqqvHiDAJvMGnAztjjqkTFCCRH/view?usp=sharing

And finally the link to the earth texture in sphere:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qQx5CGwqPFufdOIBbKiBivos_hxd7AJq/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made some changes to the code with comments.
Given two points on the surface of the sphere, I have calculated the normals to the points pointing outward. Then, I added the normals and normalized the result to get the average direction towards which, the bezier curve should lean. Multiplying this value with a factor (bulge), the height of the curve can be controlled. (Using a small value might result the curve in intersecting with the globe). I assigned the bulge factor based on the distance between the points. Here is the code:

```
float angle = 0;
float r = 200f;

Table table;
PImage earth;
PShape globe;

int rowCount;

void setup() {
  size(600, 600, P3D);

  table = new Table("From_USA_Coordinates.tsv");
  rowCount = table.getRowCount();
  earth = loadImage("world.topo.bathy.200406.3x5400x2700.jpg");

  globe = createShape(SPHERE, r);
  globe.beginShape(SPHERE);
  globe.noStroke();
  globe.endShape();
  globe.setTexture(earth);
}

void draw() {
  background(51);
  text("From USA to other Parts of the World", width/2, 50);
  textAlign(CENTER);
  translate(width/2f, height/2f);
  ambientLight(180, 180, 180);

  rotateY(angle);
  angle += 0.005f;

  shape(globe);

  for(int row = 0; row < rowCount; row++) {
    float USALatitude = radians(table.getFloat(row, 3));
    float USALongitude = radians(table.getFloat(row, 4));

    float tripCountryLatitude = radians(table.getFloat(row, 5));
    float tripCountryLongitude = radians(table.getFloat(row, 6));

    int tripCountryOccurance = table.getInt(row, 2);

    // Corrected calculations based on Processing environment. (Y points down).
    float x1 = -r * cos(USALatitude) * cos(USALongitude);
    float y1 = -r * sin(USALatitude);
    float z1 = r * cos(USALatitude) * sin(USALongitude);

    float x2 = -r * cos(tripCountryLatitude) * cos(tripCountryLongitude);
    float y2 = -r * sin(tripCountryLatitude);
    float z2 = r * cos(tripCountryLatitude) * sin(tripCountryLongitude);

    pushMatrix();
    // Calculate normal to the first point on the sphere surface
    PVector norm1 = calculateNormal(new PVector(x1, y1, z1), new PVector(0,0,0));
    // Do the same for second point
    PVector norm2 = calculateNormal(new PVector(x2, y2, z2), new PVector(0,0,0));
    // Calculate dir. This is the sum of two normals and gives an average direction towards which, the intermediate bezier points should point.
    // It theoritically bisects the two normal vectors.
    PVector dir = norm1.add(norm2).normalize();
    // Calculate distance between the points based on which, the bulge factor will apply.
    float d = dist(x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2);
    // Lower bulge might result into intersection of curve with earth.
    float bulge = 2*d / 3f;
    // Amplify the dir with bulge factor
    dir.mult(bulge);

    bezierDetail(120);
    noFill();
    stroke(255, 120);
    strokeWeight(2);

    bezier(x1, y1, z1, // First point
           x1 + dir.x, y1 + dir.y, z1 + dir.z, // First intermediate point
           x2 + dir.x, y2 + dir.y, z2 + dir.z, // Second intermediate point
           x2, y2, z2); // Final point
    popMatrix();
  }
}

// Returns normalized vector perpendicular to the point p on the surface of a sphere with the given center
PVector calculateNormal(PVector p, PVector center) {
  return p.sub(center).normalize();
}
```

Ignore the artifacts in the result. I had to highly compress the gif to post here.

[image: Result]

Hope this helps!